# Reflectance value returned from Sen2Cor

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, sentinel-snap, reflectance, sen2cor

I have a query regarding Sen2Cor atmospheric correction. I used Sen2Cor in some images but I can't find anywhere if the value it is returning me in Reflectance(Rhow) or Reflectance of Remote Sensing(rrs). In the literature, the output product is simply called Surface Reflectance,
there is no better breakdown of what it is.

Does anyone know this information about this information?

Comment: Since it shows "Sen2Cor creates Bottom-Of-Atmosphere, optionally terrain- and cirrus corrected reflectance images" in https://step.esa.int/main/snap-supported-plugins/sen2cor/. Surface Reflectance is Bottom-Of-Atmosphere reflectance.